# Java Database Handling Performance Suggestion

Tags: java, oracle, performance

I'm working on Java application which reads records from oracle database table and does some processing after reading each record.
Note: Application only reads data from database , it doesn't write back anything.

I'm using standard jdbc driver, connection, prepared statement and result set.
The number of records that I need to fetch is around 500000 (max).

**My current implementation:**

I have set statement fetch size to 500. (Query is a simple select statement from one table)
While reading each result set record, I'm adding each record to a java collection like this:

```
        List<HashMap<String,String>> userData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        while(resultSet.next()){
            HashMap<String,String> recordMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String key = resultSetMetData.getColumnName(i);
                String value = resultSet.getString(key);
                recordMap.put(key, value);
            }
            userData.add(recordMap);
        }
```

After adding all the rows to java collection, I'm closing the connection.

I would like your suggestions on the most efficient way to do this. I'm open to coding multi-threaded events if you think that's better.

Thank you,
Sash

Comment: If you save ALL 200000 rows in a List it is going to be memory intensive.  What are you doing with the data? can it not be `SELECT`'ed in the format you need it

Comment: @ScaryWombat No. I need to do some processing based on each record . If adding all rows in a list is memory intensive, it is advisable to keep resultset open for so long until i process all records?

Comment: Even though I say `memory intensive` this may not be a problem for you.  Are you actually facing any problems?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not really a problem so far but we haven't gone live with our application yet. I just want to make sure I use the right approach. One question: If i set fetch size to 500, and after reading every 500 records, and i spawn a thread to process 500 records, do you think it will be an advatange or become complicated?

Comment: What kind of processing needs to be done? What if you could move the prcessing logic to the data, rather than move all the data?

Comment: @BobC  I need make some api calls during processing. For each record that i get from db table, i need to make an API call and i cannot do a bulk API call.

Comment: @ScaryWombat You are absolutely right. That was the reason, i wanted to post it and get suggestions before i work on spawning threads!

Comment: If possible get the DB to do as much of the processing as possible, and then see what problems you face.  Have fun.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks mate!

Comment: Ate you sure you have to make this API call ?

Comment: @BobC Yes. Unfortunately, I don't really any option or work around :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work on your collections too.

1- If you know in advance that your list will be very big, you can work with `ArrayList Capacity`.

By default an ArrayList has an initial capacity of 10 records. When your list grows java will make continuously (small) re-allocations of the list, loosing a lot of time. If you do, for instance

```
  List<HashMap<String,String>> userData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(500);
```

you will have an initialCapacity of 500, saving a lot of re-allocations, so time.

Also the method `ensureCapacity`, which lets grow your list for an user-defined capacity, could be useful.

So if you know in advance the size of your results, or at least you have an idea, you can work with it.

Otherwise, if, after, you need only to iterate on the list, you can take into account `LinkedList`, which has constant time for the add operation (but not for positional access).

2- Think to your row data structures too, creating an object which encapsulates your resultset colums, instead that a map for each row (so a very big lot of maps, each one of which need a certain memory allocation, so resources and time), will be more efficient.

Have a look at the [CollectionFramework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html) , at the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) and [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) docs

UPDATE
Here some 'dirty' benchmarks

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class LoopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoopTest lt=new LoopTest();
        int records = 200000;
        lt.execute(records, false);
        lt.execute(records, true);
        lt.executeObj(records, false);
        lt.executeObj(records, true);
        lt.executeReflect(records, false);
        lt.executeReflect(records, true);


    }

    public void execute(int loops, boolean useCapacity){
        Date start=new Date();
        System.out.println("EXAMPLE WITH HASHMAP");
        System.out.println(start+ " time: "+start.getTime()+" Start for loops="+loops+ " and useCapacity="+useCapacity);
        List<HashMap<String,String>> userData=null;
        if(useCapacity)
            userData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(loops);
        else 
            userData=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<loops;i++){
            HashMap<String,String> recordMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                String key = j+"";
                String value = j+" val";
                recordMap.put(key, value);
            }
            userData.add(recordMap);
        }
        Date end=new Date();
        System.out.println(end+ " time: "+end.getTime()+", elapsed="+(end.getTime()-start.getTime())+" end for loops="+loops+ " and useCapacity="+useCapacity);
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

    }

    public void executeObj(int loops, boolean useCapacity){
        System.out.println("EXAMPLE WITH CLASSIC OBJECT");
        Date start=new Date();
        System.out.println(start+ " time: "+start.getTime()+" Start for loops="+loops+ ", object and useCapacity="+useCapacity);
        List<TestObj> userData=null;
        if(useCapacity)
            userData=new ArrayList<TestObj>(loops);
        else 
            userData=new ArrayList<TestObj>();

        for (int i=0;i<loops;i++){
            TestObj testObj = new TestObj();
            testObj.test1="1";
            testObj.test2="1";
            testObj.test3="1";
            testObj.test4="1";
            testObj.test5="1";
            testObj.test6="1";
            testObj.test7="1";
            testObj.test8="1";
            testObj.test9="1";
            testObj.test10="1";
            testObj.test11="1";
            testObj.test12="1";
            testObj.test13="1";
            testObj.test14="1";
            testObj.test15="1";
            testObj.test16="1";
            testObj.test17="1";
            testObj.test18="1";
            testObj.test19="1";
            testObj.test20="1";
            userData.add(testObj);
        }
        Date end=new Date();
        System.out.println(end+ " time: "+end.getTime()+", elapsed="+(end.getTime()-start.getTime())+" end for loops="+loops+ ", object and useCapacity="+useCapacity);
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

    }

    public void executeReflect(int loops, boolean useCapacity){
        System.out.println("EXAMPLE WITH REFLECTION");
        Date start=new Date();
        System.out.println(start+ " time: "+start.getTime()+" Start for loops="+loops+ ", object and useCapacity="+useCapacity);
        List<TestObj> userData=null;
        if(useCapacity)
            userData=new ArrayList<TestObj>(loops);
        else 
            userData=new ArrayList<TestObj>();



        for (int i=0;i<loops;i++){
            try{
                Class<?> objClass=Class.forName("com.test.TestObj");
                Object myObj=objClass.newInstance();


            for(int j=1;j<=20;j++){

                Field f=objClass.getDeclaredField("test"+j);
                f.set(myObj, "1");
            }
            userData.add((TestObj)myObj);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
        Date end=new Date();
        System.out.println(end+ " time: "+end.getTime()+", elapsed="+(end.getTime()-start.getTime())+" end for loops="+loops+ ", reflect and useCapacity="+useCapacity);
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

    }


}
```

TestObj is an object containing only public fields named test1...test25. For simplicity and speed i made them public, in real world you would make them private. It could be more engineered, but i'v done it quickly..

Here the output of elaboration

```
EXAMPLE WITH HASHMAP, useCapacity=false, loops=200000
Wed Feb 15 06:04:48 CET 2017 time: 1487135088903 Start for loops=200000 and useCapacity=false
Wed Feb 15 06:04:55 CET 2017 time: 1487135095922, elapsed=7019 end for loops=200000 and useCapacity=false
-------------------------
EXAMPLE WITH HASHMAP, useCapacity=true, loops=200000
Wed Feb 15 06:04:55 CET 2017 time: 1487135095922 Start for loops=200000 and useCapacity=true
Wed Feb 15 06:05:01 CET 2017 time: 1487135101073, elapsed=5151 end for loops=200000 and useCapacity=true
-------------------------
EXAMPLE WITH CLASSIC OBJECT, useCapacity=false, loops=200000
Wed Feb 15 06:05:01 CET 2017 time: 1487135101073 Start for loops=200000, object and useCapacity=false
Wed Feb 15 06:05:01 CET 2017 time: 1487135101254, elapsed=181 end for loops=200000, object and useCapacity=false
-------------------------
EXAMPLE WITH CLASSIC OBJECT, useCapacity=true, loops=200000
Wed Feb 15 06:05:01 CET 2017 time: 1487135101254 Start for loops=200000, object and useCapacity=true
Wed Feb 15 06:05:01 CET 2017 time: 1487135101274, elapsed=20 end for loops=200000, object and useCapacity=true
-------------------------
EXAMPLE WITH REFLECTION, useCapacity=false, loops=200000
Wed Feb 15 06:05:01 CET 2017 time: 1487135101274 Start for loops=200000, object and useCapacity=false
Wed Feb 15 06:05:05 CET 2017 time: 1487135105562, elapsed=4288 end for loops=200000, reflect and useCapacity=false
-------------------------
EXAMPLE WITH REFLECTION, useCapacity=true, loops=200000
Wed Feb 15 06:05:05 CET 2017 time: 1487135105562 Start for loops=200000, object and useCapacity=true
Wed Feb 15 06:05:09 CET 2017 time: 1487135109711, elapsed=4149 end for loops=200000, reflect and useCapacity=true
-------------------------
```

As you'll see using capacity brings the hashmap example from about 7 secs to 5.1 secs.

Using objects in classical way brings to 181 msec (!) and even 20 msec (!!) using capacity in array.

With reflection performance goes to around 4 secs indipendently from the use of capacity (4288 vs 4149).

Note that exact timing of benchmarks may vary from execution to execution. But in general the time order is always the same.

About getting your record in 'chunks' its quite a good solution for memory consistency, especially if your elaboration may be long. Often long running queries may have a "Snapshot too old" error which may create problems. And also it's not sure that performance will soffer much from this.
In the past I've to deal with something similar and a very good solution was putting a field "chunk_id", with an index, in the source table, which made easy repeating my query for the 'next' rows, and gave me more efficiency than retrieving all the content of the table. In general you just need a way to identify your groups of records from, say, group 1, group 2, .. group n (and put indexes there, of course.

PS the example for reflection is simple, but it's just to show how to do, you can work with a lot of features including methods etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On point 2.  I can create an object to encapsulate my result set columns. But i have a problem. Currently the columns that i fetch from DB is configurable and if i have an object i lose the felixibility to <NOT HARDCODE or map columns in code>

Comment: In that case, you can't do otherwise, I believe. But it depends from how many configurations you can have, of course. Is your table really changing a lot ?

Comment: Actually it will never change, only the configuration mapping may change, in short, i need to map table columns to some internal fields, this is configuration and i will lose this flexibility if i use objects

Comment: you could just map object fields to those internal fields too, using reflection.That may have a little performance disadvantage (but probably much less than allocating thousands and thousands of maps), and a little bit more programmatic effort. Maybe you can do a benchmark. If I've time tonight i'll show you an example

Comment: Thanks mate! I will look for reflection to map fields. When you have some time, kindly point me to some link or a small example, thank you!

Comment: Anyway, first check if you really need it, making benchmark of your current situation. I mean developing on reflection may make you loose time, for a thing that maybe don't give you a so big gain.

Comment: Yes, i'm also considering another option to keep the connection open but fetch records in batches. So, i get batch 1: 5000 records write them to specified complex collection,  close resultset, process them and use same prepared statement to fetch next 5000 records. This should be safer right as far as memory is concerned? I'm fine even if the job runs for 2 hours for 500k records as it's a background job. My first priority is memory and consistency. Next would be to optimize performance.

Comment: Java Tutorial on Reflection https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/
Another Tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Comment: see the edit in my answer for examples and benchmarks

Comment: Thanks Mate. I have tried a combination of records in chunks, hashmaps (i couldn't really find difference in processing time when compared to objects when i process records in chunks) and usecapacity and i'm so far satisfied with the performance.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question depends on the relative speed of your SQL query compared to the API call you need to make, along with how much memory you have compared to the size and number of your records.

Without knowing any of that, it's hard to know.

If the API calls are relatively slow and you have plenty of memory:

1. Create an [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a number of threads that you tune
2. Query your database, and send each row one by one to be executed by executor

If the query is relatively slow or you have little memory:

1. Partition your select statement into, say 8 queries, each of which returns a different part of the data
2. Create 8 threads
3. Each thread runs a query and calls the API as each row is returned by Oracle